# Mysql select data from 2 tables based on ID from one table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables. I need to select data from one table based on the ID from another table.

The tables are:

**first_table**

```
user_id
4      
5      
6
```

**second_table**

```
post_id|meta_key  |meta_value   |
1      |email     |test@test.com|
1      |first_name|test         |
1      |last_name |hey          |
2      |email     |test@test.com|
2      |first_name|test         |
2      |last_name |hey          |
3      |email     |test@test.com|
3      |first_name|test         |
3      |last_name |hey          |
4      |email     |4th@test.com |
4      |first_name|4th fname    |
4      |last_name |4th          |
5      |email     |test@test.com|
5      |first_name|test         |
5      |last_name |hey          |
6      |email     |test@test.com|
6      |first_name|test         |
6      |last_name |hey          |
```

I need data as:

```
post_id|first_name|last_name|email
4      |4th fname |4th      |4th@test.com
```

The same i will get this data for the post_id 5,6. The ID's will come from `first_table` `user_id` column.

Comment: Try my answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MAX()` and `CASE` helps you to get your result.

Try this:

```
select post_id
    ,max(case when meta_key='first_name' then meta_value end)first_name
    ,max(case when meta_key='last_name ' then meta_value end)last_name 
    ,max(case when meta_key='email' then meta_value end)email
from second_table
where post_id in(select user_id from first_table) 
group by post_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do an inner join of both the tables and since you want to see the output at the `user_id` level, you can aggregate other fields with a MAX(or even other function since these are all text values) based on the `meta_key` that is going to convert to a column.

```
SELECT A.USER_ID,
MAX(CASE WHEN B.META_KEY = 'FIRST_NAME' THEN B.META_VALUE END) AS FIRST_NAME,
MAX(CASE WHEN B.META_KEY = 'LAST_NAME' THEN B.META_VALUE END) AS LAST_NAME,
MAX(CASE WHEN B.META_KEY = 'EMAIL' THEN B.META_VALUE END) AS EMAIL
FROM
FIRST_TABLE A
INNER JOIN
SECOND_TABLE B
ON A.USER_ID = B.POST_ID
GROUP BY A.USER_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT first_table.user_id,second_table.post_id,second_table.meta_key  ,second_table.meta_value first_table LEFT JOIN second_table ON first_table.user_id=second_table.post_id;
```

if you need condition wise use where clause in last of query
where user_id=4

Answer (score 0):

The demo tables you are displaying is a wrong way of storing data. The correct way of storing data is the Store user details in user table and post details in post table separately. Then add primary key of user table as a foreign key of post table.
Then You can execute queries to get results like above.

Answer (score -1):

you can try it without using inner join

```
   function userdata($id){
        $SQL = "SELECT user_id FROM first_table where user_id= :id;
        $q = $this->DBcon->prepare($SQL);
        $q->execute(array(':id' => $id));
        $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $postid = $data[post_id]
        $sql2 = "SELECT post_id, first_name, last_name, email FROM second_table Where post_id = $postid";
        $q = $this->DBcon->prepare($SQL2);
        $q->execute();
        $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```